# Moving huge local files to HDFS using java

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I have about 20 millions files stored on my local file system, each file 5k represents a tweet.

This stored as the following:

> /home/username/tweets/$tag/$year/$month/$day/$tweetid.txt
>
> Example1 : /home/username/tweets/SCP/2014/04/11/9989443342233.txt
>
> Example1 : /home/username/tweets/WDR/2014/02/08/5890321764568.txt

So is it possible to write a map reduce java program to move all tweets under a certain tag to a singe directory in HDFS based on the tag.

Any similar examples?

Comment: Best way is to copy it to HDFS using copyFromLocal, then process them using Apache Hive or other big data tools.

Answer (score 1):

As seen in https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2009/02/the-small-files-problem/,

Make the sequencefile first, then upload it to HDFS.